# R - efficiently encrypting a string in R

Tags: r, string, encryption, vector

I wrote a script to encrypt and decrypt strings in R, the first part of the code defines a vector containing a set of characters. Then, I create an encryption dictionary by shuffling the vector and assigning names to each. This part is temporary, eventualy I will have a fixed encryption vector. Where I am having trouble is in writing my encryption and decryption functions efficiently. I get the desired output, but I feel that there is a more elegant way to get there - one that requires less computing. Ideas that come to mind are replacing the for loops with lapply (or vapply), finding an alternative for not having to convert the string into a vector, using regular expressions, and so on. However, I am new to R and have not been able to master its power. Here is my code:

```
# Script to encode and decode strings.
# Useful for passwords, email messages
# that do not contain images, and other
# text applications.


# Steps to create a vector containing all characters

## Numeric characters
nums <- c("1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
         "8", "9", "0")
## Symbols
sym <- c("!",  "@",  "#",  "$",  "%",  "^",  
         "&",  "*",  "(",  ")",  "-",  "_",  
         "=",  "+",  "[",  "{",  "]",  "}",  
         "|",  "\\", ":",  "/",  "?", ".",  
         ">",  "<",  ",",  "`",  "~",  ";", 
         "'", " ")

## Vector with numeric, symbols, and letters
chars <- c(LETTERS, letters, sym, nums)

# Create a code vector

## Randomly sorted 'chars' vector
code <- sample(chars)

## Assing names to facilitate coding and decoding
names(code) <- chars


# Define a string to code and decode
text <- "Hello World!"


# Function to code string
coder <- function(text, code){

  # Make string into a vector to facilitate iteration
  # over items
  t <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(text), split=''))

  # Initiate a vector to store coded vector
  new <- c()

  # For loop to code each element in the vector
  for(i in 1:length(t)){
   new <- c(new, names(code)[which( code == t[i])])
  }

  # Collape vector into string
  paste(new, collapse = '')
}  

# Function call to verify output
encoded_str <- coder(text, code)
print(encoded_str)

decoder <- function(text, code){

  # Make string into a vector to facilitate iteration
  # over items
  t <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(text), split=''))

  # Initiate a vector to store decoded vector
  new <- c()

  # For loop to decode each element in the vector
  for(i in 1:length(t)){
    new <- c(new, code[[t[i]]])
  }

  # Collape vector into string
  paste(new, collapse = '')
}

# Function call to verify output
decoded_str <- decoder(encoded_str, code)
print(decoded_str)
```

Comment: Is this just for educational purposes, or production?

Comment: Personal use and (self) educational purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt at a solution with simply matching elements between vectors and reordering them:

```
coder2 <- function(text, code){
    textSplit <- unlist(strsplit(text, ""))
    codeAsText <- code[code %in% textSplit]
    paste(names(codeAsText[match(textSplit, codeAsText)]), collapse = "")
}  
decoder2 <- function(text, code) {
    textSplit <- unlist(strsplit(text, ""))
    textAsCode <- code[names(code) %in% textSplit]
    paste(textAsCode[match(textSplit, names(textAsCode))], collapse = "")
}
```

[image]

PS.: Don't use `t` as name as `t` is `base` function for transposing.

Comment: @AlejandroGarciadeParedes This is not a tidy solution, but probably the fastest one as no loops are used

Comment: No loops that seen, the loops are there at a lower level. <g>